# Couldn't sign up on Careers.stackoverflow with my location

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, location, sign-up

I live in Hong Kong, which is a city on its own. Ideally, just "Hong Kong" should work, since it is both a city and a Special Administrative Region under China.

Nonetheless, it didn't let me sign up regardless of what I tried.
The error stated that I had to specify a city
 - Hong Kong
 - Hong Kong, China
 - `<District-Name>`, Hong Kong
 - `<District-Name>`, Hong Kong, China

I signed up with "San Francisco, CA, USA" just to be sure that it was my location causing the issue.
Does the profile page use a different geocoding service? I changed it to "Hong Kong" in the profile page and it worked fine, though it displays it as "Hong Kong, Hong Kong".

EDIT: The same applies to Macau as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes our geo data providers say "Hong Kong" is a city, other times they say it's a state.

I've now updated our code with a <s>hack</s> special exemption so that we should always treat Hong Kong (and Macau) as cities.

This means we now regard these locations as specific enough for creating profiles, so please try again!